# the error is in this code is "ReferenceError: rowObj is not defined" when i click on delete buttton

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function addRow(tableID) {  
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);  
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);  
        //Column 1  
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");  
        element1.type = "button";  
        var btnName = "button" + (rowCount + 1);  
        element1.name = btnName;  
        element1.setAttribute('value', 'Delete'); // or element1.value = "button";  
        element1.onclick = function () { removeRow(btnName); }  
        cell1.appendChild(element1);  
        //Column 2    
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;  
        //Column 3  
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);  
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");  
        element3.type = "text";  
        cell3.appendChild(element3);  
    
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);  
        var element4 = document.createElement("input");  
        element4.type = "text";  
        cell4.appendChild(element4); 
    }  
    function removeRow(button1) {  
        try {  
            var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');  
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
            for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {  
                var row = table.rows[i];  
                var rowrowObj = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];  
                if (rowObj.name == btnName) {  
                    table.deleteRow(i);  
                    rowCount--;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        catch (e) {  
            alert(e);  
        }  
    }
```

```html
 <BODY>  
          <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />  
          <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">  
               <TR>  
                    <TD><input type="button" name="button1" value="Delete" onclick="removeRow('button1')"></TD>  
                    <TD>1</TD>  
                    <TD><input type="text" value="" name="nameTxt"></TD>  
                    <TD><input type="text" value="" name="nameTxt"></TD> 
                   
               </TR>  
          </TABLE>  
     </BODY>
```

Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table   
            
               function addRow(tableID) {  
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);  
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);  
        //Column 1  
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);  
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");  
        element1.type = "button";  
        var btnName = "button" + (rowCount + 1);  
        element1.name = btnName;  
        element1.setAttribute('value', 'Delete'); // or element1.value = "button";  
        element1.onclick = function () { removeRow(btnName); }  
        cell1.appendChild(element1);  
        //Column 2    
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);  
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;  
        //Column 3  
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);  
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");  
        element3.type = "text";  
        cell3.appendChild(element3);  
    
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);  
        var element4 = document.createElement("input");  
        element4.type = "text";  
        cell4.appendChild(element4); 
    }  
    function removeRow(button1) {  
        try {  
            var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');  
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;  
            for (var i = 0; i

Comment: You  have  defined rowrowObj, not rowObj. So that's the reason it's giving undefined when you are trying to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined rowrowObj, not rowObj. So that's the reason it's giving undefined when you are trying to access it.